# Has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift

I referred lot of links to solve similar issue..please help
Many links suggest to solve such issue search for the buggy library info list and delete the Executable define there.., Xcode will regenerate it.
If i don't do this i get error during Export/(creating ipa file) after Archiving.
If i do this then i get error like:(Using simulator)

Bundle at path /Users/MacBook/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/4AD1D213-8D7C-4DDC-85B2-D6887F51DC74/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.HuwLlU/extracted/Payload/meeting.app/Frameworks/FontAwesome_swift.framework has missing or invalid CFBundleExecutable in its Info.plist

If i run it on device..i get error like:
Application does not have executable

No idea how to solve such issues..please help

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to run the wrong target. You can't execute a framework; it needs to be included in some other executable

Comment: Make sure you uncheck the 'Include bitcode' checkbox, otherwise you will continue getting errors with that bundle once you have deleted the reference of it in info.plist

Comment: I need to include font awesome framework manually then..do you have any idea how to do this..as currently i have used cocoapods to add fontawesome framework...and this may be reason i am getting this error

Answer (score 13):

in info.plist add key **Executable file** with value  **$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)**

Comment: This worked for me - it should be an accepted answer

Comment: This is like using a variable. How can I check the value that gets used in Xcode itself and not after building the app and checking the .app file.